# How to count the number of filtered elements in a chain of iterator adapters

Tags: rust, filter, iterator, mutable, borrow

I have a chain of iterator adapters (which I don't know the number of at compile time) applied to an initial iterator.
A simplified example would be to filter a range of numbers by their divisibility and obtain the number of remaining numbers at the end:

```
    let n: usize = 10;
    let mut iter_chain: Box<dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item = usize>> = Box::new(1..=n);

    for i in 2..n {
        iter_chain = Box::new(iter_chain.filter(move |j| j % i != 0));
    }

    println!("{}", iter_chain.count());
```

Now, I want to **count the numbers of elements** in each *stage* of this filter chain.

My idea is to insert between each filter a `inspect` adapter that increases a counter for the corresponding *stage*.
However, each `inspect` adapter has to borrow the mutable counter from somewhere outside of the loop.
This leads to multiple mutual borrows of the Vector in which I store the counters at the moment.

```
    let n: usize = 10;
    let mut iter_chain: Box<dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item = usize>> = Box::new(1..=n);

    let mut filter_overview = vec![0; n];
    for i in 2..n {
        // cannot borrow `filter_overview` as mutable more than once at a time
        //                                                   |
        //                                                   V
        iter_chain = Box::new(iter_chain.inspect(|_| filter_overview[i] += 1)); 
        iter_chain = Box::new(iter_chain.filter(move |j| j % i != 0));
    }

    println!("{filter_overview:?} {}", iter_chain.count());
```

The expected values of `filter_overview` in this example are `[10, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]`.

Is there a workaround for this problem, or do I have to use something different than a Vector to store these counters?
Maybe there is an entirely different way to achieve this?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1137b3d7688cd8a4257805e903bf4971)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using interior mutability, you can do that by iterating over `filter_overview`. You need to be careful to declare it before `iter_chain`, however, otherwise it will be used after it's freed:

```rust
let n: usize = 10;
let mut filter_overview = vec![0; n];
let mut iter_chain: Box<dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item = usize>> = Box::new(1..=n);

for (i, overview) in std::iter::zip(2..n, &mut filter_overview) {
    iter_chain = Box::new(
        iter_chain
            .inspect(|_| *overview += 1)
            .filter(move |j| j % i != 0),
    );
}

println!("{filter_overview:?} {}", iter_chain.count());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using either interior mutability or atomics. With atomics, the vector becomes `Arc<Vec<AtomicU64>>` (or whichever atomic type you choose). The result looks like ([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c0a233ced518f15af9ebb43a0fcc67fc)):

```rust
use std::sync::{
    atomic::{AtomicU64, Ordering},
    Arc,
};

fn main() {
    let n: usize = 10;
    let mut iter_chain: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>> = Box::new(1..=n);

    // AtomicU64 isn't Clone, so can't use vec![] syntax.
    let filter_overview = Arc::new(Vec::from_iter(
        std::iter::repeat_with(|| AtomicU64::new(0))
            .take(n)
    ));
    
    for i in 2..n {
        // Get a fresh reference by cloning the Arc.
        let overview = filter_overview.clone();
        
        // Use a move closure to move the new Arc into the iterator.
        iter_chain = Box::new(iter_chain.inspect(move |_| {
            overview[i].fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
        }));
        
        iter_chain = Box::new(iter_chain.filter(move |j| j % i != 0));
    }

    println!("{filter_overview:?} {}", iter_chain.count());
    println!("Desired output: {:?}", [10, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]);
}
```

The output is

```
[0, 0, 10, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1] 1
Desired output: [10, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

Comment: There is no need for `AtomicU64` here, or any other atomic type, since no thread-synchronization is needed. Using atomics is basically just there because `.fetch_add()` takes a `&self`, avoiding the `&mut`-borrow of `overview`. The same could and should be achieved via a `Cell`.